# Linking existing YouTube channel to Google Apps account

Tags: youtube, google-workspace, google-plus

We had a YouTube channel under a Gmail account. Since then we have
signed up for Google apps business and we want to use this for all access
to Google services where possible.

This is what we tried so far:

- We have linked our (Gmail) YouTube account to our Google+ page (attached to same account).
- We have then added several Google apps users as managers to the Google+ page, and
  they can successfully log in and manage etc.

But when trying to access YouTube (using Google apps account) and switching account to the name of the Google+/YouTube channel, we are prompted with the following prompt:

> "Create a channel for … From your Google+ Page"

and we do not have access to the existing channel.

Is there anything we can do about this?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that we had linked our YouTube account to the Google+ profile but we had added the managers to the Page.

Unlinking YouTube from the profile and re-linking to the Page seems to have made it work.